# Renaming all columns within multiple files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to rename the column headers for approximately 50 files. Each file has 8 columns. The first contains a row number and then the remaining 7 are those that I'd like to rename. I wrote the function below, but it spits out the following error:

*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/someone/Python/pandas/studysession/brand_studies/existing_consumer_status/clean_files.py", line 54, in 
mapping()
File "/Users/someone/Python/pandas/studysession/studies/existing_consumer_status/clean_files.py", line 15, in mapping
old_names = df.columns[column_indices]
~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/someone/Python/pandas/studysession/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 5380, in **getitem**
result = getitem(key)
^^^^^^^^^^^^
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1*

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
os.chdir('/Users/someone/Python/pandas/studysession/studies/existing_consumer_status/survey_data/')

csv_files = glob.glob('/Users/someone/Python/pandas/studysession/studies/existing_consumer_status/survey_data/*.csv')

def mapping ():
    for csv in csv_files:
        df = pd.read_csv(csv)
        column_indices = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
        new_names = ['Awareness','Brand_Recall','Consideration','Purchase_Intent','Ad_Recall','Product_Use','User_Id']
        old_names = df.columns[column_indices]
        final_df = df.rename(columns=dict(zip(old_names, new_names)))
        
        out = csv +'_survey_final.csv'
        final_df.to_csv(out)

mapping()
```

The expected output is to have the 7 columns renamed using an index to the following names:

'Awareness','Brand_Recall','Consideration','Purchase_Intent','Ad_Recall','Product_Use','User_Id'

I want to use an index because the current/original names of the columns differ slightly.

Comment: please add the full error message traceback

Comment: And the expected output

Comment: Which line gives you the error? And what's the `df.columns` when error occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pandas is an overkill

```
csv_files = glob.glob('/Users/someone/Python/pandas/studysession/studies/existing_consumer_status/survey_data/*.csv')
newcol="Awareness,Brand_Recall,Consideration,Purchase_Intent,Ad_Recall,Product_Use,User_Id\n"
for csv in  csv_files:
    allines=open(csv).readlines()
    indx=allines[0].split(",")[0]
    allines[0]=indx+","+newcol
    with open(csv +'_survey_final.csv',"w") as f:
        f.write(''.join(allines))
###end
###adjust delimiters if they are different
```

far more efficient would be if you know column header of first column
if its was row_no

```
newcol="Row_no,Awareness,Brand_Recall,Consideration,Purchase_Intent,Ad_Recall,Product_Use,User_Id\n"
for csv in  csv_files:
    data=open(csv).read()
    data=data[data.find("\n"):]
    with open(csv +'_survey_final.csv',"w") as f:
        f.write(newcol+data)
```

Answer (score 3):

You're close, you just need a *listcomp* to avoid the `IndexError` :

```
old_names = [df.columns[i] for i in column_indices] # <- here

final_df = df.rename(columns=dict(zip(old_names, new_names)))
```

**Update**: as pointed by @jezrael, `df.columns[column_indices]` should also work.

The IndexError means probably that at least one of your files (*for some reason*) has less 7 than columns.

I suggest you to include an `if..else` statement right before slicing `df.columns` :

```
if len(df.columns) >= max(column_indices):
    old_names = df.columns[column_indices]
    final_df = df.rename(columns=dict(zip(old_names, new_names)))
else:
    final_df = df
    print(f"The File/DataFrame {csv} has less than 7 columns!")
```

Comment: hmm, also working `df.columns[column_indices]` - so it seems data related problem.

Comment: You're right, maybe a `delimiter` problem in the csv that makes the columns less than 7 ?

Comment: Or some file has 7 columns, not 8.

Comment: Thank you jezarel, I updated my answer accordingly ;)